# Key sequence for going up in the directory tree with Dired?

Tags: dired

When Dired is open, It would be cool if I could press one key and go up in the directory tree, to the parent directory. I have this feature in vim with netrw and I'd like to recreate it.

I'd like to press `-` and I go back (or up in the dir tree)

I'm not sure where I should get started with figuring it out.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Dired, by default **`^`** (command `dired-up-directory`) does what you ask.

You can find this by using **`C-h m`** (command `describe-mode`) in a Dired buffer. After a general description of the mode it lists the keys bound locally in the mode, including `^`.

If you want to also bind `-` to the command then use this:

```lisp
(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "-") 'dired-up-directory
```

However, `-` is bound in Dired to `negative-argument`, as an abbreviation for doing `C-u -`.  So to act on the previous 3 lines you can just use `- 3` instead of `C-u - 3`.  You might want to keep that behavior...

---

If you use library [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) ([code](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/dired%2b.el)) then `^` is bound to command `diredp-up-directory`, which is an improved version of `dired-up-directory`. From the doc string:

> With a prefix arg, Dired the parent directory *in another window*.
>
> On MS Windows, if you are already at the root directory, invoke
> `diredp-w32-drives` to *visit a navigable list of Windows drives*.

Comment: My biggest challenge with emacs is finding out the name of functions that do things. Thanks Drew!

Comment: @Vinn Start `M-x` then enter `dired-` and press TAB to see a list of commands whose name start with `dired-`. Even if you don't guess the “up” part of the name, you can at least guess the “directory” part of the name and enter `M-x dired-directory` then press TAB twice and out of the box this only offers three functions (“clean”, “create”, “up”) out of which “up” is the obvious candidate. Alternatively, use a command description search: `C-u C-h d dired parent RET` finds just `dired-up-directory`.

Comment: This is really good advice. I will test that next time when I have a problem!

Comment: My advice is to always start with `C-h m`, to get info about the current context (major and minor modes). And there's `C-x b`. ;-)